# what does ~= do in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

I can't seem to find out what "~=" does in JavaScript. I was look at this [tutorial](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) and I saw that. I couldn't figure out what the symbol is called so if they asked this already, please tell me and I'll delete this post, thanks in advance. The specific line is:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(/* time */ time){ 
  // time ~= +new Date // the unix time 
});
```

Comment: Nope because that one is different, I know that one is a bitwise operator but what does it do with the equal sign

Comment: But then what is it with the equal sign?

Comment: @androidmaster what is `+` with the `=` sign?

Comment: Guys if it is a duplicate please don't -rep, I'll just delete it, please dont do -rep since then I wont be able to ask more questions

Comment: Please show code in the question. Then we'll have a chance. There is no ~= operator in Javascript unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: I dont think thats a valid javascript operator... though in pseudo code you might use it to say approximately equal to

Comment: + with the = sign is += which adds onto the number

Comment: I saw in the tutorial, scroll down where it saids `window.requestAnimationFrame(function(/* time */ time){
  // time ~= +new Date // the unix time`
});

Comment: No. Put it in the question. Off site links are no good.

Comment: Yes but its commented out in the tutorial so it might just be shorthand for approximately equal to... while not being valid javascript

Comment: Okay, shall I delete this post or leave it?

Comment: Why did i get -1 oh no i have only one 1 left to ask before i get banned

Comment: Thank you who ever donated rep, I will forever admire you

Comment: `var t = 5; t ~= 100;`: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ~`. So the answer to your question is: It does nothing because it's a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks shouldn't that be the an answer